# Get SoundCloud Artist Page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, soundcloud

I'm trying to write a function in JavaScript where the user can type in an artist, and it will return a link to that artist's SoundCloud page. For example `!artist beyonce` --> `https://soundcloud.com/beyoncemusic` I have researched a lot but still can't figure out how to do this simple task. Does anyone know how?

Comment: How are you planning on mapping the artist's name (which in this case is beyonce) to the actual URL part (which is not beyonce, but beyoncemusic)?  Do you just tack "music" onto the end of the name?

Comment: Well that's the problem really. The SoundCloud URLS don't all act the same. For example, `!artist calvin harris --> https://soundcloud.com/calvinharris` and `!artist dave matthews band --> https://soundcloud.com/dave-matthews-band`

Comment: Then you're going to need some sort of cross-reference to look up the URL, probably from the SoundCloud API.  Have you had a look there, to see what they have?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought as well, but I didn't see any sort of URL look up for this. Here's what I looked at: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference

Comment: Yes, that's the page alright.  If I were to answer your question, that's where I'd have to research to answer it.  I assume it has sub-pages. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hit the search endpoint of the sound cloud API. Checkout the API's documentation.

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#search

```
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<script>
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID' 
});
// find all sounds of buskers licensed under 'creative commons share alike'
SC.get('/tracks', { q: 'buskers', license: 'cc-by-sa' }, function(tracks) {
  console.log(tracks);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Does your code example retrieve the artist's URL given the artist's name, or is it just a general example of API usage?

Comment: That's the API's description.

Comment: It would be a better answer if it actually answered the OP's question.  Is the artist's URL in one of the tracks?

Comment: Though this doesn't tell me how to do it exactly, it's actually given me a point in the right direction. Thanks for your help, you too Robert

Comment: Try this URL:http://api.soundcloud.com/users?q=shakira&license=cc-by-sa&client_id=d3dad53735c089de11e00abc42cd091a&format=json&_status_code_map[302]=200. The main problem is you really can't tell which account is the artist's official one. On the code above, you'd have to change the/tracks for /users and change the value for q

Comment: Ok I'll try this thanks. I may just take the top hit.

Comment: I created a .html file and pasted the code from above, then opened it in FireFox and used the FireBug to capture the URL that javascript code is hitting, which is what I pasted on the comment. Of course, changing the endpoint (/tracks to /users) and the keyword.